# Thread-safe Lua

Tags: c#, multithreading, lua, thread-safety

Situation: I have a multi-threaded server application that an undefined amount of clients connect to. On server start, I create a Lua state, setting up all functions, and for each new connection from a client, I create a child state with `lua_newthread`. At "random" points during the connection, the client might request something that is supposed to be handled by Lua, so I look up the function that is supposed to run for the client's request and call it. This function might then also call a function in the host application, the server, that yields the execution, with `lua_yield`, to wait for a response to something from the client. When that response comes in, I resume the connection's Lua state. Essentially I have two access points to Lua, `Call` and `Resume`.

Now, I know Lua in itself is not thread-safe, and if I don't protect the global state, what I'm currently doing will potentially fail with multiple clients. A [tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ThreadsTutorial) I read recommends modifying Lua, to implement locking functions, that already wrap every operation in Lua's code.

My question is, if I wrap my `Call` and `Resume` calls in C# `lock` blocks, that use the same object of course, would that protect the global state effectively as well? If only one call is ever let through to the Lua VM? Or is there a case where this is somehow not enough?

Example:

```
private object syncLock = new object();

public void Call(IntPtr L, string functionName)
{
    lock(syncLock)
    {
        lua_getglobal(L, functionName);
        lua_resume(L, 0);
    }
}

public void Resume(IntPtr L, string response)
{
    lock(syncLock)
    {
        lua_pushstring(L, response);
        lua_resume(L, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a lock on the Lua state should be enough.

Comment: Locking the connection's Lua state wouldn't help I think, as that belongs only to the connection. I could lock the global state, but whether I use that, or a dedicated lock object doesn't make a different I guess.